# Error at System.Net.Sockets.Tcpclient.Connect<String hostname, Int32 port>

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, tcpclient

I am trying to establish `TCP` connection between my console application and PIC Microcontroller. Here the behavior is strange. Some time I am able make connection and sometime not. The behavior is total random. Code is given below along with the snap of the error which i am getting.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    TcpClient tcpclnt1 = new TcpClient();
                    Console.WriteLine("Connecting.....");

                    tcpclnt1.Connect("10.112.90.246", 13002);
                    // use the ipaddress as in the server program

                    Console.WriteLine("Connected");
                    Console.Write("Enter the string to be transmitted : ");

                    String str = Console.ReadLine();
                    Stream stm = tcpclnt1.GetStream();

                    ASCIIEncoding asen = new ASCIIEncoding();
                    byte[] ba = asen.GetBytes(str);
                    Console.WriteLine("Transmitting.....");

                    stm.Write(ba, 0, ba.Length);

                    //byte[] bb = new byte[100];
                    //int k = stm.Read(bb, 0, 100);

                    //for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
                    //    Console.Write(Convert.ToChar(bb[i]));

                    tcpclnt1.Close();
                }

                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error..... " + e.StackTrace);
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

**ERROR**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Error With Message

Comment: Print the e.Message output

Comment: Or just the whole exception, basically... which will automatically include any nested exceptions, which could be relevant.

Comment: Have you done any ethernet logging (e.g. wireshark) to check whether your PIC is in fact responding correctly to your TCP connection attempts?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the IP Adress instead of the host name, the Connect methode which takes a string as a parameter expects a DNS host name and not an IP-Adress:

```
public void Connect(string hostname, int port)
```

> hostname
>
> Type: System.String
>
> The DNS name of the remote host to which
>   you intend to connect.

Use either the hostname or the [method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkbhht5w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which takes an IP as parameter isntead
See [Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s2yca91%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)